# Passing values to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

In my controller i have IActionResult, which takes 3 strings

```
public IActionResult DeviceDetails(string idDetails, string begindate, string enddate)
{....}
```

I like to pas this strings from web page, where user can chose begin and end date from datepicker, so i have:

```
<input id="begindate" type="date" class="btn btn-default"/>
<input id="enddate" type="date" class="btn btn-default" />
<button type="submit" value="show data" class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Show data", "DeviceDetails", new { idDetails = ViewBag.DeviceName, begindate ="begindate", enddate = "enddate" }) </button>
```

How can i pass values from  `id="begindate"` and `id="enddate"` to `Html.ActionLink` (idDetails works fine)?
Or,  how can i pass this two string to controller in different way?

Comment: You cannot do that in c# nor in HTML. You need to look at JavaScript for these kind of problems. You also could look at building a proper ViewModel instead of receiving 3 strings, so you wouldn't need to concatenate everything in the URL

Comment: you need to set the name attribute as same as ActionResult Parameter name.

Comment: @Piotr Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @ Murat- Yes, working fine, for my purposes  easier ways to use Tetsuya Yamamoto, solution, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate `ActionLink` using temporary placeholder values inside `routeValues` and put an ID to anchor element:

```
<button type="submit" value="show data" class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Show data", "DeviceDetails", new { idDetails = ViewBag.DeviceName, begindate = "xxxx", enddate = "yyyy" }, new { id = "showdata" })</button>
```

Then, use plain JS/jQuery to handle `click` client-side event which replaces temporary placeholder values into real values from date input (below is using jQuery):

```
$('#showdata').click(function(e) {
    var beginDate = $('#begindate').val();
    var endDate = $('#enddate').val();
    var tempValue = $(this).prop('href');
    var realValue = tempValue.replace("xxxx", beginDate)
                             .replace("yyyy", endDate);
    location.href = realValue; // redirect
    return false; // cancel default redirect
});
```

As a side note, better to use a strongly-typed viewmodel and pass input values to controller action method using viewmodel properties rather than building large amount of query strings.

Live example: [DotNET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lVAo8X)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**ActionLink (default):**

```
@Html.ActionLink("YourAction", "YourController", new { id = item.ID })
```

***ActionLink (using Button):***

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController",
    new { Model.ProductID })';return false;">Details</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" title="Details" value="Details" onclick="location.href=
    '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController", new { id = item.ID })'" />
```